# ParseException: mismatched input '2022' expecting {<EOF>, ';'}

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following PySpark/SQL code:

```
extracted_at = "2022-01-31 00:00:00"
extracted_at_date = "2022-01-31 00:00:00"
current_fiscal_period = (sqlContext.sql('SELECT CUR_PER FROM TBM_PARMS').first()[0])
current_reporting_fiscal_period = sqlContext.sql('SELECT CUR_PER FROM TBM_PARMS').first()[0]

query = "SELECT PER_END_DATE FROM GLM_PERIOD_END WHERE PERIOD = {}".format(current_fiscal_period)
current_reporting_fiscal_period_end = sqlContext.sql(query).first()[0]

query2 = "SELECT CASE WHEN {} > {} THEN {} ELSE {} END".format(extracted_at_date, current_reporting_fiscal_period_end, current_reporting_fiscal_period_end, extracted_at_date)
current_reporting_date = sqlContext.sql(query2).first()[0]
```

I am getting the following error:

```
ParseException: mismatched input '2022' expecting {<EOF>, ';'}(line 1, pos 17)
== SQL ==
SELECT CASE WHEN 2022-01-31 00:00:00 > 2022-05-31 00:00:00 THEN 2022-05-31 00:00:00 ELSE 2022-01-31 00:00:00 END
-----------------^^^
```

I cannot figure out the error in the SQL. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is missing the `'`

You may try:

```
query2 = f"SELECT CASE WHEN '{extracted_at_date}' > '{current_reporting_fiscal_period_end}' THEN '{current_reporting_fiscal_period_end}' ELSE '{extracted_at_date}' END"
```

or

```
query2 = "SELECT CASE WHEN '{}' > '{}' THEN '{}' ELSE '{}' END".format(extracted_at_date, current_reporting_fiscal_period_end, current_reporting_fiscal_period_end, extracted_at_date)
```

Btw, I think it would be a good idea to parse those timestamps as date/time/timestamp and not deal with them as strings.

Comment: However, I do not understand why. Can you explain why the ```'``` is necessary?

Comment: I agree, better to parse as timestamps. The final version of the code will do this.

Comment: because it is a string, you need to use ```'```. Otherwise the syntax will not be correct like ```SELECT CASE WHEN 2022-01-31 00:00:00``` It will understand 2002 as an integer but It gets lost when the ```-```is found